# jqplot inner donut overlapping & legend only showing outer donut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I am setting up a donut chart with two levels using jqplot, but there two problems and I have a sneaky suspicion that they are related.

1. When I leave the settings to default it displays correctly, but as soon as I start setting diameter, innerdiameter, etc. The dimensions apply to both the inner and outer charts and they overlap. Could anyone help me? (go easy on me, I'm new to this, and really appreciate the help). I have set up an example at http://jsfiddle.net/oniiru/GFJrw/1/
2. I have the legend displaying, but it will only show for the outer donut, the inner one won't show no matter what I do.

I would really appreciate any help you all could give me. As I said, I'm very new to this and could really use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re. point 1. I don't think it's possible to customise the donut chart in the way you want using those parameters. BUT what you can do is play with the size of the div the chart is displayed in, the padding on the chart and the ringMargin between the two donuts and this might help with what you want to achieve.

re. point 2. It seems that when displaying multiple series on a donut chart like this, there is an assumption that the two series will be describing the same data set. In your specific case, if you add the additional fields, with a zero value, to each of the series, it will show all the values in the legend.

Both points are illustrated in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EjcyY/